# Most accurate way to compute asinhf() from log1pf()?

Tags: c, math, floating-point, floating-accuracy

The inverse hyperbolic function `asinh()` is closely related to the natural logarithm. I am trying to determine the most accurate way to compute `asinh()` from the C99 standard math function `log1p()`. For ease of experimentation, I am limiting myself to IEEE-754 single-precision computation right now, that is I am looking at `asinhf()` and `log1pf()`. I intend to re-use the exact same algorithm for double precision computation, i.e. `asinh()` and `log1p()`, later.

My primary goal is to minimize ulp error, the secondary goal is to minimize the number of incorrectly rounded results, under the constraint that the improved code would at most be minimally slower than the versions posted below. Any incremental improvement to accuracy, say 0.2 ulp, would be welcome. Adding a couple of FMAs (fused multiply-adds) would be fine, on the other hand I am hoping someone could identify a solution which employs a fast `rsqrtf()` (reciprocal square root).

The resulting C99 code should lend itself to vectorization, possibly by some minor straightforward transformations. All intermediate computation *must* occur at the precision of the function argument and result, as any switch to higher precision may have a severe negative performance impact. The code must work correctly both with IEEE-754 denormal support and in FTZ (flush to zero) mode.

So far, I have identified the following two candidate implementations. Note that the code may be easily transformed into a branchless vectorizable version with a single call to `log1pf()`, but I have not done so at this stage to avoid unnecessary obfuscation.

```
/* for a >= 0, asinh(a) = log (a + sqrt (a*a+1))
                        = log1p (a + (sqrt (a*a+1) - 1))
                        = log1p (a + sqrt1pm1 (a*a))
                        = log1p (a + (a*a / (1 + sqrt(a*a + 1))))
                        = log1p (a + a * (a / (1 + sqrt(a*a + 1))))
                        = log1p (fma (a / (1 + sqrt(a*a + 1)), a, a)
                        = log1p (fma (1 / (1/a + sqrt(1/a*a + 1)), a, a)
*/
float my_asinhf (float a)
{
    float fa, t;
    fa = fabsf (a);
#if !USE_RECIPROCAL
    if (fa >= 0x1.0p64f) { // prevent overflow in intermediate computation
        t = log1pf (fa) + 0x1.62e430p-1f; // log(2)
    } else {
        t = fmaf (fa / (1.0f + sqrtf (fmaf (fa, fa, 1.0f))), fa, fa);
        t = log1pf (t);
    }
#else // USE_RECIPROCAL
    if (fa > 0x1.0p126f) { // prevent underflow in intermediate computation
        t = log1pf (fa) + 0x1.62e430p-1f; // log(2)
    } else {
        t = 1.0f / fa;
        t = fmaf (1.0f / (t + sqrtf (fmaf (t, t, 1.0f))), fa, fa);
        t = log1pf (t);
    }
#endif // USE_RECIPROCAL
    return copysignf (t, a); // restore sign
}
```

With a particular `log1pf()` implementation that is accurate to < 0.6 ulps, I am observing the following error statistics when testing exhaustively across all 2<sup>32</sup> possible IEEE-754 single-precision inputs. When `USE_RECIPROCAL = 0`, the maximum error is 1.49486 ulp, and there are 353,587,822 incorrectly rounded results. With `USE_RECIPROCAL = 1`, the maximum error is 1.50805 ulp, and there are only 77,569,390 incorrectly rounded results.

In terms of performance, the variant `USE_RECIPROCAL = 0` will be faster if reciprocals and full divisions take roughly the same amount of time, but the variant `USE_RECIPROCAL = 1` could be faster if very fast reciprocal support is available.

Answers can assume that all basic arithmetic, including  FMA (fused multiply-add) is correctly rounded according to IEEE-754 round-to-nearest-or-even mode. *In addition*, faster, nearly correctly rounded, versions of reciprocal and `rsqrtf()` *may* be available, where "nearly correctly rounded" means the maximum ulp error will be limited to something like 0.53 ulps and the overwhelming majority of results, say > 95%, are correctly rounded. Basic arithmetic with directed roundings *may* be available at no additional cost to performance.

Comment: If you want accuracy, ditch `float` and move to `double` asap, or even `long double` if your compiler supports 80-bit real number representation.

Comment: That is not a realistic option for performance reasons, all intermediate computation must occur at the "native precision" of the input and result. I'll edit that requirement into the question.

Comment: `double` is more native than `float`, which is now only suitable for some very restricted systems like embedded.

Comment: Your question is "most accurate way" so I suggest you cut to the chase and not have to go through your tests all over again.

Comment: By "native" I meant "the same type as used in the function prototype". There are commonly used platforms (GPUs) where `float` operations can have *significantly* higher throughput than `double` operations, and on many platform including x86 with AVX there is no convenient way to use any type wider than `double`.

Comment: So you *can* use `double` for better accuracy.

Comment: @WeatherVane "Most accurate" under the constraints I outlined. I have clarified the question with regard to the use of higher precision in intermediate computations, what other clarifications do you think would be needed.

Comment: Yes, all platforms I am considering do have `double` support but it may be up to 32x slower than `float`, so not practical given the need for high performance. In addition I am using the `float` version as an experimental platform for the `double` version, and there is no hardware support for any higher precision beyond `double`

Comment: Please make your mind up. Do you want `double` or do you want `float`? Do you want *speed* or do you want *accuracy*? You said, in the question, before moving to `double`. My first comment stands.

Comment: I want the best accuracy *under the constraints stated*, that is, without totally screwing performance. The question as written is about the `float` case, but I am intending to re-use the same algorithm for `double` later, as I mentioned at the start of the question.

Comment: My assessment of your `my_asinhf()` using `#if !USE_RECIPROCAL` is also worst case error of about 1 [ULP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) at `a == 7.517228127e-01` and an average error of 1/8 ULP.  I do not think a _more_ accurate answer is feasible with approaches used.  Perhaps a [Minimax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax_approximation_algorithm) polynomial?

Comment: A minimax polynomial is certainly a possibility I considered, and is my usual "plan B" for such issues. But before I go there, I wanted to check whether I am missing something regarding possible re-arrangements of the arithmetic. For example, is there an arrangement where either a `sqrt` or `rsqrt` (a contracting operation) is used late, rather than early in the computation? Can FMA be used more effectively than it currently is to improve accuracy? Is there a way to implement `sqrt1pm1` that would help accuracy (I have no practical experience with that function)?

Comment: I'm unclear on the value of accuracy versus speed. May I surmise correctly that you want maximum ULP error about 0.5-0.6-ish and better speed performance, using your posted solution as the function to beat?  Or do you want 2x+ speed and allowing a couple up to 2.0 ULP ?

Comment: Ideally I would like to retain the performance of my posted variants, but achieve better accuracy. I will take any accuracy improvement I can get, e.g. 0.2 ulp better than the current code. If a more accurate solution would require, say, a couple more FMAs, I could live with the performance impact. Conversely I am hoping someone can find a way to exploit a fast `rsqrt`. Getting to a faithfully-rounded implementation (< 1 ulp) would be great. My current thinking is that shooting for any bound tighter than that would definitely mean negatively impacting performance, which I want to avoid.

Comment: @chux After spending considerable additional time researching this, the only solution I found that reduces the error further than my variant `#if !USE_RECIPROCAL` is to compute the input to `log1pf()` as a double-float `arg_hi, arg_lo`, then compute `asinh()` as  `fmaf (arg_lo, 1.0f/(1.0f+arg_hi), log1pf (arg_hi))`. When using a correctly rounded `log1pf()` this reduces the error in `asinhf()` to 1 ulp. This is not practical from a performance perspective because it requires either higher precision or expensive double-float computation for the argument transformation.

Comment: Why the specific constraint that the implementation reduce computing `asinhf` to computing `log1pf`?

Comment: That is a very common way of computing `asinh()`, and happens to be the one I am currently exploring in detail. The attractiveness of such a general approach is that one can build implementations for various math functions from just a few building blocks, with inverse hyperbolic functions in particular being mapped back to `log1p()`. Since the difficult arguments for `asinh()` are all small, one could use a minimax polynomial for those, but that would be a yet another code branch (not advantageous if the goal is a vectorizable implementation), and worthy of a separate question.

Comment: Are you familiar with [Table Maker's Dilemma](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/jean-michel.muller/Intro-to-TMD.htm)?

Comment: I am very much familiar with TMD, how does this figure into my question, though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After various additional experiments, I have convinced myself that a simple argument transformation *that does not use higher precision than the argument and result* cannot achieve a tighter error bound than the one achieved by the first variant in the code I posted.

Since my question is about minimizing the error for the argument transformation which is incurred in addition to the error in `log1pf()` itself, the most straightforward approach to use for *experimentation* is to utilize a correctly rounded implementation of that logarithm function. Note that a correctly-rounded implementation is highly unlikely to exist in the context of a high-performance environment. According to the works of J.-M. Muller et. al., to produce accurate single-precision results, x86 extended precision computation should be sufficient, for example

```
float accurate_log1pf (float a)
{
    float res;
    __asm fldln2;
    __asm fld     dword ptr [a];
    __asm fyl2xp1;
    __asm fst     dword ptr [res];
    __asm fcompp;
    return res;
}
```

An implementation of `asinhf()` using the first variant from my question then looks as follows:

```
float my_asinhf (float a)
{
    float fa, s, t;
    fa = fabsf (a);
    if (fa >= 0x1.0p64f) { // prevent overflow in intermediate computation
        t = log1pf (fa) + 0x1.62e430p-1f; // log(2)
    } else {
        t = fmaf (fa / (1.0f + sqrtf (fmaf (fa, fa, 1.0f))), fa, fa);
        t = accurate_log1pf (t);
    }
    return copysignf (t, a); // restore sign
}
```

Testing with all 2<sup>32</sup> IEEE-754 single-precision operands shows that the maximum error of 1.49486070 ulp occurs at ±`0x1.ff5022p-9` and there are 353,521,140 incorrectly rounded results. What happens if the entire argument transformation uses double-precision arithmetic? The code changes to

```
float my_asinhf (float a)
{
    float fa, s, t;
    fa = fabsf (a);
    if (fa >= 0x1.0p64f) { // prevent overflow in intermediate computation
        t = log1pf (fa) + 0x1.62e430p-1f; // log(2)
    } else {
        double tt = fa;
        tt = fma (tt / (1.0 + sqrt (fma (tt, tt, 1.0))), tt, tt);
        t = (float)tt;
        t = accurate_log1pf (t);
    }
    return copysignf (t, a); // restore sign
}
```

However, the error bound does not improve with this change! The maximum error of 1.49486070 ulp still occurs at ±`0x1.ff5022p-9` and there are now 350,971,046 incorrectly rounded results, slightly fewer than before. The issue seems to be that a `float` operand cannot convey enough information to `log1pf()` to produce more accurate results. A similar problem occurs when computing `sinf()` and `cosf()`. If the reduced argument, represented as a correctly rounded `float` operand, is passed to the core polynomials, the resulting error in `sinf()` and `cosf()` is just a tad under 1.5 ulp, just as we are observing here with `my_asinhf()`.

One solution is to compute the transformed argument to higher than single precision, for example as a double-float operand pair (a useful brief overwiew of double-float techniques can be found in [this paper by Andrew Thall](http://andrewthall.org/papers/df64_qf128.pdf)). In this case, we can use the additional information to perform linear interpolation on the result, based on the knowledge that the derivative of the logarithm is the reciprocal. This gives us:

```
float my_asinhf (float a)
{
    float fa, s, t;
    fa = fabsf (a);
    if (fa >= 0x1.0p64f) { // prevent overflow in intermediate computation
        t = log1pf (fa) + 0x1.62e430p-1f; // log(2)
    } else {
        double tt = fa;
        tt = fma (tt / (1.0 + sqrt (fma (tt, tt, 1.0))), tt, tt);
        t = (float)tt;                // "head" of double-float
        s = (float)(tt - (double)t);  // "tail" of double-float
        t = fmaf (s, 1.0f / (1.0f + t), accurate_log1pf (t)); // interpolate
    }
    return copysignf (t, a); // restore sign
}
```

Exhaustive test of this version indicates that the maximum error has been reduced to 0.99999948 ulp, it occurs at ±`0x1.deeea0p-22`. There are 349,653,534 incorrectly rounded results. A faithfully-rounded implementation of `asinhf()` has been achieved.

Unfortunately, the practical utility of this result is limited. Depending on HW platform, the throughput of arithmetic operations on `double` may only be 1/2 to 1/32 of the throughput of `float` operations. The double-precision computation can be replaced with double-float computation, but this would incur very significant cost as well. Lastly, my approach here was to use the single-precision implementation as a proving ground for subsequent double-precision work, and many hardware platforms (certainly all the ones I am interested in) do not offer hardware support for a numeric format with higher precision than IEEE-754 `binary64` (double precision). Therefore any solution should not require higher-precision arithmetic in intermediate computation.

Since all the troublesome arguments in the case of `asinhf()` are small in magnitude, one could [partially?] address the accuracy issue by using a polynomial minimax approximation for the region around the origin. As this would create another code branch, it would likely make vectorization more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you may want to look into the accuracy and speed of your `log1pf` function: these can vary a bit between libms (I've found the OS X math functions to be fast, the glibc ones to be slower but typically correctly rounded).

Openlibm, based on the BSD libm, which in turn is based on Sun's fdlibm, use multiple approaches by range, but the main bit is [the relation](https://github.com/JuliaLang/openlibm/blob/5cd80c4b1c2e1ac5b95f44e76520f4d47f53e00a/src/s_asinhf.c#L46):

```
t = x*x;
w = log1pf(fabsf(x)+t/(one+sqrtf(one+t)));
```

You may also want to try compiling with the `-fno-math-errno` option, which disables  the old System V error codes for `sqrt` (IEEE-754 exceptions will still work).

Comment: My question is about minimizing the error incurred *on top of* the error due to `log1pf()`. With a correctly rounded `log1pf()`, my two `asinhf()` variants have maximum error of 1.49486 and 1.50805 ulp, respectively. With a faithfully rounded `log1pf()` [max error of 0.88383 ulp], the error in `asinhf()` grows to 1.70243 / 1.72481 ulp. With your prosed variant used in conjunction with a correctly rounded `log1pf()` the maximum error in `asinhf()` is  1.54368 ulp, so *higher* than with either of my two current variants.